# Where can I find a feed reader gadget verified by Microsoft?

Tags: windows-7, rss, desktop-gadget, feed-reader

I want a feed reader gadget for Windows 7. I search in [News and feed](http://partners.gallery.live.com/results.aspx?c=38&bt=1&pl=1) gadgets, but can't find any verified feed reader.

Where can I find a feed reader verified by Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Hermes](http://hermesgadget.codeplex.com/). While not verified by MS, it's used at MS.
[Source code](http://hermesgadget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) included.
This was on the Live Gallery before the gallery was retired.

> Hermes is a Windows sidebar gadget that displays a scrolling list of items from an editable list of RSS, RDF and Atom feeds.